# Google App Engine, are neither urllib3 nor requests supported?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I keep getting the following error when I deploy my google app:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file:
>   [/Users/app.yaml]the library "requests" is not supported

I have changed it to urllib3, but still get the same error. Following is the app.yaml:

```
# entrypoint: main.py
# env: flex
# runtime: python

runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
  - name: ssl
    version: latest
  - name: lxml
    version: latest
  - name: urllib3
    version: latest
  - name: flask
    version: latest
```

And the invocation of the library:

```
# from requests import get as rget 
from urllib3 import PoolManager
http = PoolManager()
query = some_query
# page = rget(query)
page = http.request('GET',query)
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue could be. I have seen previous stack overflow answers which ask me to pip install in the lib, and add it to requirement.txt too, but none of these seem to make a difference.

Is there any other library that does exactly the same but is natively supported by google app engine ?

Answer (score 0):

App Engine supports third party libraries in two ways in the standard Python 2.7 environment.

- [Built-in libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27): these are automatically enabled in the cloud if [declared](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime) in your `app.yaml` file.  You may need to install them locally with `pip` [to make them available in the dev server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#local_development).
- Other third party libraries: these libraries must be `pip` installed into a folder in your application and uploaded as part of your deployment. The folder must be [declared](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library) in your `appengine_config.py`.  These libraries **must not** be declared in `app.yaml`, or you get the error you're reporting.

`requests` and `urllib3` are not included in the built-in libraries so you will need to:

1. [Set up vendored libraries folder](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library) in appengine_config.py
2. `pip install -t <your-lib-folder> requests` (`urllib3` is installed as part of requests I believe).
3. Ensure `<your-lib-folder>` is uploaded when you deploy to the cloud.